# using gets in c programming is wrong

Tags: c, fgets, gets

I am trying to read a string of characters in C:
If I use gets, the compiler doesnt read my word, because it considers ENTER as being my string, I guess. I tried using

```
scanf("%*c")
```

but then if i do that and type "flower", the variable stores the string "lower". If I use

```
scanf("%s",s)
```

then the compiler doesn`t store anything after I hit space.
If I use

```
fgets(s,20,stdin)
```

I have the exact same problem as if I used gets.
What should I do?

Comment: `scanf("%*c")` ?? missing second argument...

Comment: Please mind that it's not the compiler which reads your words. It's your program.

Comment: how do you print your string?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan : the `%*c` will read and discard the character , which don't have to pass any arguments

Answer (score 1):

Simply "remove" the newline if it's in the end of the string:

```
if (fgets(s, 20, stdin) != NULL)
{
    while (strlen(s) > 0 && s[strlen(s) - 1] == '\n')
        s[strlen(s) - 1] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: +1 but I'd `size_t len = strlen(s)` rather than call `strlen()` 3x.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getchar()` and `ungetchar()` to solve this problem , Like this :

```
char c;   
while((c=getchar())<=' ');
ungetchar(c);
```

the code above will remove any unwanted spaces or enters before the string , then you can `gets` as you want

Comment: This code will also consume any `char` in the range `CHAR_MIN` to `' '`.  Maybe instead `int c;  while(isspace(c = getchar()));`

Comment: There is : tab = 9 , line feed and carriage return = 10,13 and space = 32 , the others are control chars

Answer (score 0):

scanf() does not read the string after space. In short, it reads continuous string but fgets() is defined to read characters(space also). In my compiler Dev-C++ & 64-bit operating system, fgets() is reading characters including space. Note space is also a character defined with ASCII value.